# Embedded Jetty 9: How to create a request to pass to RequestDispatcher from scratch?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to create and feed requests from code (server initialization) to JSPs using Jetty 9.2. This is mainly for warmup/precompilation but also other reasons. I do not have an ongoing request (this is happening at startup) and I would like to avoid the workarounds that actually send requests using the network.

Problem I face right now is that the following line (83) in Jetty's Dispatcher.java fails with a null pointer exception:

```
Request baseRequest=(request instanceof Request)?((Request)request):HttpChannel.getCurrentHttpChannel().getRequest();
```

So, how does one properly feed requests code-created requests into embedded Jetty? Pleas help.

Answer (score 0):

Dispatcher requires a valid request.

As the dispatched call requires a bunch of information from the Request (such as method, headers, content encodings, what sort of response encodings are valid, uri, context path, sessions, cookies, security contexts, principals, etc.  the list is long)

Comment: Yes, it does. Trouble is, no matter how valid I may make it, it seems to require something that appears to be ThreadLocal which is only set up if the request comes in otherwise. There has to be a way to feed requests high up enough, maybe higher than RequestDispatcher...